# How do I write to the console regardless of whether or not the user uses `|` or `>` operators on the shell?

Tags: ruby, console, stdout

I wrote a program in Ruby and have been writing all data to the console with `puts`.

If I run `my.rb` from the console I can redirect the stream to a file both with `>` and `|`.

How should I change stdout in order for data to be written to the Windows console?

Comment: Why should your program need to know where the user wants the output to go? What if your program is run by an automated process with no console to speak of? Far better to leave stdout and stderr as abstract output sinks which can be redirected by the user as needed.

Comment: "which can be redirected by the user as needed" - so, how to redirect output to console ?

Comment: By the user, and not by the writer of the program. stdout/stderr will print to the console by default, if a user runs the program from an interactive shell. If the user wants it to go to a file, though, I see no reason why that shouldn't happen. And as I mentioned, an automated process that might be designed to run the program independently from user interaction will have no console at all.

Answer (score 3):

The whole idea of those symbols is to allow users of your app to redirect the output to their desired place. This is useful for logging, filtering, and any number of other applications where you want the output of one program to be the input of another program or file. It's facilitates a form of inter-process communication that often isn't possible otherwise.

Essentially, unless you can more clearly define the *reason* you want to do this (a specific case where this is useful and desirable) you should not try to do this, nor am I sure it's even possible, because those symbols operate at the shell level. I don't think there is anything within the scope of Ruby that you can do what will have any effect whatsoever on where the output goes. The shell (after it's already left your Ruby program) is capturing that output and redirecting it. By that point, that data/output is already out of the control of your Ruby app.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to differentiate from real "output" and error messages that the user should see, you can instead send output to the standard error output with something like:

```
$stderr << 'oh noes!'
```

The standard error output is redirected independently from the standard output.

Comment: what should i do if i want to change behaviour of puts? i wanna puts to write to console; I don't want to write directly to stderr(

Comment: So no matter what the user does, you want to be able to output to the console?